# Shortcode returns only first value for a loop

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

the shortcode given below returns only the first value:

```
function completed_quiz(){
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userID = $current_user->ID;
    $fetch22 = $wpdb->get_results("MySQL Query");
    foreach($fetch22 as $item){
    return "Quiz ID: $item->quiz_id Percentage: $item->result <br>";
    }
}   
add_shortcode('show_completed_quiz', 'completed_quiz');
```

However if I use "echo" it gives all the values. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In foreach ,store all the value in some variable and then return that variable after foreach loop

```
    function completed_quiz(){
      global $wpdb;<br/>
       $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
       $userID = $current_user->ID;
       $fetch22 = $wpdb->get_results("MySQL Query");

       $returnVal ='';

       foreach($fetch22 as $item){

        $returnVal .= "Quiz ID: $item->quiz_id Percentage: $item->result <br>";

       }

       return $returnVal ;
     }
```

add_shortcode('show_completed_quiz', 'completed_quiz');